# How to access to the element in the nested Json (Map<String, Object>) data and modify the data by using java.util.stream

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, stream

I would like to modify the data inside nested json (Map<String, Object>) by using java.util.stream.

This is Json Data

```
{
      "schoolId": "10928391",
      "schoolName": "school A",
      "teachers" : [
        {
          "teacherId": "00001",
          "teacherName:": "teacher A",
          "subject": "Computer Science",
          "lectures": [
            {
              "id": "CS102",
              "name": "Algorithm"
            },
            {
              "id": "CS330",
              "name": "Data Communications and Networking"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "teacherId": "00002",
          "teacherName:": "teacher B",
          "subject": "Computer Science",
          "lectures": [
            {
              "id": "CS103",
              "name": "Data Structure"
            },
            {
              "id": "CS104",
              "name": "Data Structures in C++"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "teacherId": "00003",
          "teacherName:": "teacher C",
          "subject": "Computer Science",
          "lectures": [
            {
              "id": "CS100",
              "name": "Introduction to Programming (Java)"
            },
            {
              "id": "CS401",
              "name": "Object Oriented Programming"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

--

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
Map<String, Object> schoolInfo = mapper.converValue(restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,  .... ).getBody(), HashMap.class);
```

the Json data above is inside schoolInfo

the data what I want to access and modify is lectures.
I tried to modify all the elements inside lectures(array).

for example,

```
"lectures": [
        {
          "id": "CS102",
          "name": "Algorithm"
        },
        {
          "id": "CS330",
          "name": "Data Communications and Networking"
        }
      ]
```

Replace all lecture information in the lecture data as follows.

```
"lectures": [
        {
          "lectureId": "CS102",
          "lectureName": "Algorithm",
          "lectureRoom": "Room A-1"
        },
        {
          "lectureId": "CS330",
          "lectureName": "Data Communications and Networking",
          "lectureRoom": "Room A-2"
        }
      ]
```

with map, filter I could access to "teachers" object
but I couldn't figure out how to get "lectures" objects inside the "teachers"

```
System.out.println(jsonMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(map -> map.getKey().equals("teachers")).collect(Collectors.toList()).toString());
```

Any advice would be very helpful !

Comment: not sure if you are deserialising your teacher object in java pojo or not. If you are then you will need to pick lectures array and then you will have to modify data. If you are not serialising to Java pojo then 1st you have to do it.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my Question. I deserialized the json object by using Mapper